# computing expectations in variational updates

Tags: self-study, bayesian, expected-value, variational-bayes

I have a complete log-likelihood expression as follows:

$$
L = \sum_{i=1}^N \log P(y_i|x_i, w_i, \beta) + \log P(\beta) + \sum_{i=1}^N \log P(w_i)
$$

Now, I need to compute the expectation of these wrt to the posterior distribution of the hidden variables $(\beta, w)$. Since they are coupled, we assume that they are independent in the posterior distributions i.e. $Q(\beta, w) \approx Q(\beta) Q(w)$ using the mean field approximation trick.

Now, I am struggling to wonder what the next step is. So now, do I compute the expectation of the log likelihood first wrt to $Q(\beta)$ and then with $Q(w)$ and then use the property that the expectation of the product is the product of these individual expectations? Is that the right way to do this?

So, assuming I know the conditional distribution $P(w|y,x, \beta)$ and the conditional distribution $P(\beta|x,y,w)$, the required expectation would be

$$
(<P(w|y,x, \beta> L) (<P(\beta|x,y,w)> L)
$$